# 64 bit LAPACK precompiled Windows Mingw

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, lapack, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build a 64 bit executable on Windows using MinGW that links to LAPACK and BLAS.  Several sources referred me to the prebuilt MinGW 64 bit lib and dll files here:
https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/

However, linking to those files fails with message "skipping incompatible x64_mingw/liblapack.dll when searching for -llapack" when I use x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe to compile and link.  Anyone know why that is?